# How to filter data in the backend for displaying geotags via GeoJSONLayerView to the Map

Tags: python, django, leaflet, postgis, geodjango

I need to display weather stations only in the areas(filter by id_ugms) of the country that the user chooses. But the geodjango tools do not allow you to filter the data in the backend. GeoJSONLayerView extracts all the data from the table, and I have to filter the entire list in leaflet on the frontend. There are a lot of records in the table, which is why the response time is very long(it takes more than 5 minutes to display and filter), or it crashes from the server altogether. How do I do backend filtering? Maybe there's another way?
I tried just to make a selection, and serialize the data via geojsonserializer - nothing worked, leaflet does not give an error of input data.
Technology stack: Postgis, Django, Leaflet.

There is a model of my entity:
models.py

```
class WeatherStation(gismodels.Model):

    id_station = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    station_index = models.IntegerField(default = None)
    name_station_rus = models.CharField(default="", max_length=256)
    name_station_en = models.CharField(default="", max_length=256)
    id_ugms = models.ForeignKey(Ugms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
    id_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None) 
    id_subrf = models.ForeignKey(Subrf, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
    latitude = models.CharField(default ="", max_length=256)
    longitude = models.CharField(default ="", max_length=256)
    geom = gismodels.PointField(default ='POINT EMPTY',srid = 4326)
    objects = gismodels.Manager()
    height_above_sea = models.CharField(default="", max_length=256)
    access_level = models.CharField(default="", max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id_station
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from obsnet import  views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import  re_path
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
from obsnet.models import WeatherStation
from obsnet.views import StationGeoJSONLayerView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

    re_path(r'^filterstation.geojson$', StationGeoJSONLayerView.as_view(), name = 'filterstation'),

  
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point, Polygon

from obsnet.models import WeatherStation
from obsnet.forms import FilterForm
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
import json

from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from djgeojson.serializers import Serializer as GeoJSONSerializer
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
from django.conf.urls import  re_path
from djgeojson.http import HttpGeoJSONResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import  reverse

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""

    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    id_s = None
    id_fed = None
    id_country = None
    id_ugms = None
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = FilterForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():

            id_ugms = form.cleaned_data.get('filter_ugms')
            if (id_ugms == '0') : 
                id_ugms = None
 
            return render(
                request,
                'obsnet/index.html',
               
                { 
                    'form' : form,
                    'title' : 'Home Page',
                    'year' : datetime.now().year,
                    'id_ugms' : id_ugms, 
                
                },        
            )

    else:
        form = FilterForm()
   
    
    return render(
        request,
        'obsnet/index.html',
        {
            'form' : form,
            'title' : 'Home Page',
            'year' : datetime.now().year,

        },        
    )

class StationGeoJSONLayerView(GeoJSONLayerView):
    model = WeatherStation
    properties = ['name_station_rus', 'station_index', 'id_subrf', 'id_country',  'id_ugms' ]
    def head(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = HttpGeoJSONResponse('')
        return response
```

index.html

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% load geojson_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .filter-map-box{
    height: 65%;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 5%; /* Расстояние сверху */
    left: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.27); 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.27);
    z-index: 9999;
    }
    .map-block{
    /*width: 75%;*/
    }
    
    .leaflet-container {  /* all maps */
                       
        width:  100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #specialbigmap {
        height: 1000px;
    }

    /* Resize the "display_raw" textbox */
    .django-leaflet-raw-textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

   
      <div class = "map-block">
    {% leaflet_map "main" callback="main_map_init" %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main_map_init (map, options) {
    

            var ugms = '{{ id_ugms }}';
            
            var suburl = '{% url "filterstation" %}';
            // Download GeoJSON via Ajax
            $.getJSON(suburl, function (filterstation) {
                // Add GeoJSON layer
                var fea = filterstation.features;
                if (ugms !== 'None') 
                {
                    
                    for (i = 0; i < fea.length; i++)
                    {
                        var prop = fea[i].properties;
                            if (prop.id_ugms == ugms)
                            {
                                console.log(idfiltr );
                                L.geoJson(filterstation.features[i]).addTo(map).bindPopup(prop.name_station_rus);
                            }
                    }
                
                }

                
            });
            
            

            map.setMaxBounds([[-90,-180], [90,200]]);
            map.options.maxBoundsViscosity = 1.0;   
        
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a rel="nofollow" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);
        
        }
    </script>
    
    </div>
    <div class = "filter-map-box">
    
        <form action="" method="post">
                <label for="id_filter_label">Фильтр</label>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }} 
                <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Отобразить"/>

        </form>

    </div>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How i would go about it using DRF(django rest framework) and more specifically djangorestframework-gis create a serializer to serializer the data to geojson as follow.

```
from .models import WeatherStation
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer

class WeatherStSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
         model = WeatherStation
         geo_field = geom
         fields = ('name_station_rus', 'station_index', 'id_subrf', 'id_country',  'id_ugms')
```

and on views.py do these

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from .serializers import WeatherStSerializer
from .model import WeatherStation

class StationGeoJSONLayerView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = WeatherStation.objects.get(id_ugms ="value you need")
        geojson = WeatherStSerializer(data=queryset, many=True)
        geojson.is_valid()
        return JsonResponse(geojson.data, content_type='json', safe=False)
```

in queryset you can use all the backend filter methods before passing the data to the serializer.
have a look at [DRF-gis](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-gis/)